# LibreOffice Calc new line in cell format code

Tags: format, newline, libreoffice-calc

Is it possible to put new line character in cell format code?
For example to have week day name under the date in the same cell?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a format code, use a formula.  Either enter `CHAR(10)`, or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> in a different cell and then reference that cell in the formula.

```
=TEXT(TODAY(), "DD-MMM-YYYY") & CHAR(10) & TEXT(WEEKDAY(TODAY()),"DDDD")
```

See https://superuser.com/questions/85439/how-can-i-make-a-newline-in-an-openoffice-org-calc-formula.

Be sure that the row is tall enough to show both lines.